# in Ember Data how do you manually load a Record with a hasMany association for unit testing?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i'm unit testing computed properties on a DS.Model .

```
// a trivial example that i'm not actually testing
App.ModelA = DS.Model.extend({
    sub_models : DS.hasMany('App.ModelB'),

    lengthOfBees : function() {
         return this.sub_models.length;
    }.property('sub_models.length')
})
```

how do i manually create a record that has an association?  providing json for a record with no associations is easy..  App.ModelX = App.ModelX.createRecord({ attribA : 'valueA'});

but i don't know the syntax for createRecord when i want to supply the hasMany associations.  how do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using ember-data rev 12 this should work

```
  test("findMany QUnit test example", function() {
    store.load(Person, {id: 9, name: "Toran Billups"});
    person = store.find(Person, 9);
    store.loadHasMany(person, 'tasks', [ 1, 2 ]);

    var tasks = get(person, 'tasks'); //to fire the http request

    equal(get(tasks, 'length'), 2, "");
  });
```

And if loadHasMany doesn't work in your version of ember-data try this instead

```
  test("findMany QUnit test example", function() {
    store.load(Person, {id: 9, name: "Toran Billups", tasks: [1, 2]});
    person = store.find(Person, 9);

    var tasks = get(person, 'tasks'); //to fire the http request

    equal(get(tasks, 'length'), 2, "");
  });
```

Comment: thanks for the help so far.  this is close to what i'm looking for, but i'd rather not do the get(person,'tasks') line to fire an http request and then have to use sinon to send back task json data.  isn't there a way to manually load all json data into the store for the associations?

Comment: what if you load each task before you load the person object? then when you do a find it will be wired up automatically (no http request needed)